# Linq to SQL Association combo box order

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, ide

This is kind of a weird question and more of an annoyance than technical brick wall.

When I'm adding tables and such using the Linq-to-SQL designer and I want to create an association using the dialogs. I right click on one of the target tables and choose *Add* > *Association* as normal and I am presented with the **Association Editor**.

The *Parent Class:* and *Child Class:* combo boxes are filled with the tables that currently exist in the designer.

But they are not in alphabetical order they are in the order that they were added to the designer.

Can I change the order of these combo boxes? And if I can, where do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went poking around some and found an answer.

The **dbml** file is an XML file that hold all of the basic information about the SQL tables, connections, etc. needed for Linq-to-SQL. By reordering the Table elements, you affect the order of the combo boxes used in the Association editor.